# FCM not showed image (not icon) in background

Tags: firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

This is my code for send push It's working BUT not showing the image in the background.

Note: I am working with WEB push and not android or ios.

Is there any way to send the full image in the background with web push using FCM?

URL: https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send
POST
AUTH

JSON:

```
{
   "notification":{"title":"Jumbo +",
              "imageUrl":"someimage.png",
              "icon":"someimage2.png"
              "click_action":"someurl"
              },
      "registration_ids":[token],
      "data":{"image":"someimage.png"},
      "time_to_live":1000
 }
```

Comment: Organized the question structure and did some spell checking and grammar corrections